# unexpected password field in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, backend

I'm creating a registration system with django REST framework so i can use it with React js. Here is my serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers 
from backApp.models import Client 

class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)
    
    class Meta:

        model = Client 
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'password2']

        extra_kwargs = {

            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

        def save(self):

            client = Client(

                email = self.validated_data['email'], 
                username = self.validated_data['username'],
            )

            password = self.validated_data['password']
            password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

            if password != password2:

                raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match'})

            client.set_password(password)
            client.save()

            return client
```

and here is my views.py file:

```
from rest_framework import status 
from rest_framework.response import Response 
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework import permissions
from authentication.api.serializers import RegistrationSerializer

@api_view(['POST',])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def registration_view(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        
        if serializer.is_valid():

            client = serializer.save()
            data['response'] = "successfully registred!"
            data['email'] = client.email
            data['username'] = client.username
            
        else: 

            data = serializer.errors 

        return Response(data)
```

whenever i make a POST request with POSTMAN (look at the image )
[image]

I get the following error:
`TypeError: Client() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password2'`

How can i fix this please ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to move out `save()` method from `Meta` class to the serializer class itself:

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)
    
    class Meta:

        model = Client 
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'password2']

        extra_kwargs = {

            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        client = Client(
            email = self.validated_data['email'], 
            username = self.validated_data['username'],
        )
        # rest of your code
```